# What's the point of ArrayController in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

The documentation has an example of using an `ArrayController` with this template:

```
{{#each MyApp.listController}}
  {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
{{/each}}
```

This is how the `ArrayController` is used:

```
MyApp.listController = Ember.ArrayController.create();

$.get('people.json', function(data) {
  MyApp.listController.set('content', data);
});
```

How would this work differently than using a plain array like this instead?

```
MyApp.listController = [];

$.get('people.json', function(data) {
  MyApp.set('listController', data);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the behavior of a controller, you can use a plain array.

An ArrayController wraps an array, with some other properties added, such as the sortable mixin.
You can see it here:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/array_controller.js

Answer (score 5):

in the ember.js documentation says:

(http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.ArrayController.html)

> The advantage of using an ArrayController is that you only have to set
>   up your view bindings once; to change what's displayed, simply swap
>   out the content property on the controller.

it uses an Array in background, only helps with methods to work with the array:

> Although you are binding to the controller, the behavior of this
>   controller is to pass through any methods or properties to the
>   underlying array